# EURO Symbol is converted to ? Symbol using FB and IBX

Tags: delphi, firebird

When I want to store the EURO (€) symbol using the `TIBQuery` or `TIBScript` component, it is converted to the ? symbol. But when I use my Firebird DB management tool, I can store the € symbol. That means, the DB can store it.

What to I have to do, in order I can store the € symbole in my Firebird DB using IBX compnents?

I am using Delphi XE, Firebird 2.5 and the IBX components to access the database.
The charset is set to "ISO8859_1" in Firebird and in the IBDatabase component.

Comment: Delphi XE is Unicode. Isn't ISO8859_1 unicode? TEncode is set to CodePage=88591 in the components.

Comment: No, `ISO8859_1` is a rather lame 8 bit encoding. Use Unicode.

Comment: What do you mean, use Unicode? Do you mean, I should use Charset UTF8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should stop using the very limited 8 bit ISO8859 encodings for your data. Use a Unicode encoding instead. For instance, UTF-8 is usually the best choice.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the euro symbol is only in the Charset ISO8859 15

Comment: Hm ... when I use my DB management tool (Firebird Maestro) I can store and see the EURO symbol. Furthermore, the Charset ISO8859_15 doesn't exist to select.

Comment: @max Then your tool does some conversions of its own (eg maps the Euro to some byte and on retrieval displays it as Euro), because the Euro symbol most certainly does not exist in ISO8859_1 (ISO8859_15 was introduced to add the Euro).

Comment: Most likely that tool is using Windows-1252

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera True, but if the connection characterset is ISO8859_1 then it shouldn't display a Euro symbol, so it probably does some fudging, because ISO8859-1 symbol 0xA4 is ¤, not € (0xA4 in -15), nor 0x80 (€ in Windows-1252)